# Being RESTful with status codes and behaviour for Put and Delete best practices

Tags: http, rest, model-view-controller, restful-url

i got some RESTful best practice questions:

1) If the server receives a DELETE request, and finds a resource and deletes it. What's good practice to respond with? 200 OK seem most natural to me, but you also have codes such as 202 Accepted. Using the latter might make it more obvious to the Client that it is something that the Server handles, rather than just responding OK.

2) If the server receives ANOTHER DELETE request on the same resource. What's best practice here, do you respond with 404 Resource not found, or do you just respond 200 OK (or 202 OK), with the reasoning that DELETE and PUT should be idempotent?

3) Server receives a PUT request, but the record couldn't be found in the database. What do you respond with? 404? Some other code with the goal that we want to tell the client that it's not a true "web 404" but that it's just the fact that we looked for it but the resource could not be found?

4) When do you respond with messages more than just status codes?

> 200 OK {"Message": "Customer was deleted"}

Feels redundant.

Answer (score 0):

1) I don't understand. 200 is correct here. 202 is something else ("The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed.").

2) It doesn't matter. Really.

3) Then create the record.

4) If you don't have more to say than OK then don't.

Comment: Julian. 


2) Really? How about thinking in terms of Idempotency?  GET, HEAD, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS and TRACE are all intended to be idempotent operations; that is, “the side-effects of N > 0 identical requests is the same as for a single request.” (RFC2616 §9.1.2)


3) But PUT should only update resources, and using PUT states that you know something of the resource (its locator) such as it's ID. Right? Clients should not be allowed to create resources with their own ID's.

Comment: 2) The side effect is the same; just the status code is different. 3) PUT can also create resources. There's nothing wrong with that *if* you want to allow the client to select their URIs. You don't have to support it, but you can.